# I'm trying to call method from another class but it is undefined

Tags: java, fits

I've created a method *sReadFitsData* within the class *ReadFitsData*. I want to call this method in any class. For example, from the class *TestRead*. But instead I've got a compilation error: "**The method sReadFitsData(String) is undefined for the type TestRead**".

Here is my code:

**ReadFitsData.java**

```
package readFits;

import java.io.IOException;

import nom.tam.fits.BasicHDU;
import nom.tam.fits.Fits;
import nom.tam.fits.FitsException;
import nom.tam.fits.Header;

public class ReadFitsData {

public int[][][] sReadFitsData(String fitsFileName) throws IOException, FitsException {
    int[][][] myData;
    Fits f; // fits object
    Header hdr;
    Object fData;

    try {
        f = new Fits (fitsFileName); 
    } catch (FitsException fEx) {
        throw new IOException ("Failed to open FITS file; "+fEx.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        BasicHDU hdu = f.getHDU(0); // 0 is for first header, 1 is for second one.
        f.close();
        //hdr = hdu.getHeader();

        //int size = (int) hdr.getDataSize();

        fData = hdu.getData().getData(); // Object fData
    } catch (FitsException fEx) {
            throw new IOException ("Failed to get Data; "+fEx.getMessage());
    }


    if (!fData.getClass().isArray()) {
        throw new IOException ("Unknown HDU Data type: " + fData.getClass().getName());// + fEx.getMessage());
    }

    myData = (int[][][]) fData; // cast the fData to an int[][][]

    return myData;
}

}
```

Another class for call this method:

**TestRead.java**

```
package readFits;

public class TestRead {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String fname = "myFitsFile.fits";
        int[][][] arr = sReadFitsData(fname); // here is the compilation error.
    }

}
```

---

**ADDITION according to the answer:**

First I did my method *sReadFitsData* as *public static* for independence of objects.

Second I made an import of a class:

**TestRead.java**

```
import projectName.readFits.ReadFitsData;
```

And the same compilation error persists. Should it be?:

```
int[][][] arr = sReadFitsData(fname); // error is still there
```

When I'm putting this code with or without import it's ok:

```
int[][][] arr = ReadFitsData.sReadFitsData(fname); // working!
```

Comment: What do you mean when you write "a set of 1-D arrays"? A multi-extension FITS file? A table? In the former case from the looks of it you would probably use ImageHDU. In FITS (almost) any homogeneous N-D array is referred to as an" image" because traditionally, well, it was an image. But it doesn't have to be. As far as FITS is concerned it's just some bytes along with some metadata (in the header) saying how to iterate over those bytes.  What actually are you trying to do though and what problem are you running into?  The code you posted above is incomplete.

Comment: When I googled nom.tam.fits the second hit was a tutorial on how to use it. Not great, but better than nothing. Maybe the above insight that any N-D array in FITS is called an "image" will help. Also does it have to be Java? I don't know what you're doing but it might be less cumbersome to do with Python. Of course that all depends what your purpose is...

Comment: By "a set of 1-D arrays" I mean that my data is a multi-array with 3 dimensions e.g. [620,90,2]. I want to read data from the fits file into this array. [This image representing my data](https://s18.postimg.io/fj58kqq9z/271214az16fok0.png) .

Comment: There is no tutorial because it doesn't contain a samples of working code. Only general description.

Comment: So that would probably be stored as a 3-D "image" in FITS.  So what exactly is the problem?  Have you tried using Python instead, and Astropy.  Astropy's FITS library actually has documentation :)  (Not great either, I'll admit, but better).

Comment: I'm not interested to use any other language. I can do it easily in IDL, but I need to solve this in java.

Comment: Alright, but what exactly is the problem?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I think, finally I've solved this.

Comment: Still need a help.

Comment: You keep editing your question to the point that it no longer in any way resembles your original question, which if I recall was for basic help on using this library.  Now you've changed it to asking about a basic error in Java for which you provide no context for any other readers.  Part of the point of Stack Overflow is not just to get help, but ask questions and get answers that may be useful to other readers in the future.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  For detailed help with `nom.tam.fits` they might have a mailing list or something you can reach out to.

Comment: wat? I don't understand you. There is a full context. I've asked a question that might be useful for others. What is the problem? Why I can't get an answer? My question isn't useful?

Comment: I've improved my question and hope it isn't so terrible now.

Comment: You need to create an instance of that ReadFitsData class before you can call its methods, since it's not a static method.

Comment: You've asked like three different questions by editing the same question over and over again.  That's why it's confusing and not conducive to getting help.  It's better now though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to call methods from different `classes` (more specific: different files), you need to `import` those `classes`.

The thing is, how should the class `TestRead` know who the method `sReadFitsData` is, at least it's no method from himself.
Another thing is, what to do if `TestRead` would also define a method named `sReadFitsData`, you want somehow to be able to distinguish between both methods.

There are two ways you can solve this issue. First, you can specify the `full class path` in front of the method call. You do so by exchanging the call in `TestRead` with: `readFits.ReadFitsData.sReadFitsData(fname)`.
The full class path consists of all packages and the class itself.

Second, you can `import` the class, what you probably want to prefer in this case. Simply add this line to the beginning of the `TestRead` class, right after the package declaration: `import readFits.ReadFitsData;`
It should then look like the other imports of your `ReadFitsData` class.

Okay, that was the first problem. However, it won't compile now either. You must create an instance of the class `ReadFitsData` and call the method on it:

```
ReadFitsData data = new ReadFitsData();
data.sReadFitsData(fname);
```

If you want the method to be independent of objects, you need to make it `static`:

```
public static int[][][] sReadFitsData(String fitsFileName) throws ... {
```

Then you can call the method by `ReadFitsData.sReadFitsData(...)` from anywhere (after importing).

At this point I should say that you're struggling with some really basic `Java` things. It may be better for you to read or watch some beginner tutorials or books :)

You may get an `IDE`, for example `eclipse`, for working with `Java`. Those programs will automatically import classes as they detect which method you probably want to use. Also they let you choose if there are multiple.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! According to your answer I've made an addition to find out is there a way to not creating an object and not writing full path.